# Exponential in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

How to find exponential calculation for [1-(1+0.025)^-2] in Ms-Excel 2007.
When i do this in calculator i got 0.048185604 as result.

I already tried like this in excel

```
=1-((1+0.025)*EXP(-2)) .
```

I got 0.861281335 as result.

I didn't get expected result.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Check HELP for the EXP function.  It is NOT the same as the exponentiation operator **^**

Comment: ya i will check..but i got expected result

Comment: The equivalent Excel native function is [POWER()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-function-HP010342773.aspx), e.g =1-POWER(1+0.025, -2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter it in Excel, preceded with an equal sign:

```
=1-(1+0.025)^-2
```

Result:  0.0481856038072576